# Example of an algebra finite over a commutative subalgebra with infinite dimensional simple modules

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $A$ be an algebra over an algebraically closed field $k.$ Recall that if $A$ is
a finitely generated module over its center, and if its center is a finitely generated
algebra over $k,$ then by the Schur's lemma all simple $A$-modules are finite dimensional
over $k.$

Motivated by the above, I would like an example of a $k$-algebra $A,$ such that:

1) $A$
has a simple module of infinitie dimension over $k,$

2) $A$ contains
a commutative finitely generated subalgebra over which $A$ is a finitely generated 
left and right module.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: No, but you could use it as a homework problem if you wish.

Comment: Is there a reference for the statement in the first paragraph?  And are there familiar (noncommutative) infinite dimensional algebras meeting these conditions?   The motivation here needs some reinforcement.  For me the interesting examples are universal enveloping algebras of finite dimensional Lie algebras in prime characteristic, where Schur's lemma isn't enough to prove finite dimensionality of all simple modules.  (Ditto for quantized enveloping algebras or function algebras at a root of unity.)

Comment: @Jim: I don't know the exact reference, but one could prove it as follows. Let V be a simple A-module. Without loss of generality
we may assume that the annihilator of V is 0. Let Z denote the
center of A. It follows that V is f.g. Z-module and any nonzero
element of Z acts invertibly on V (Schur's lemma), so Nakayama's
lemma implies that Z is a field. But by the
assumption Z is a finitely generated algebra over an algebraically closed field k. Therefore Z=k and V is finite over k.

Comment: I can't follow the last steps in your sketch and would prefer a reference.   A textbook version I recall (following Jacobson's original line of proof) treats only universal enveloping algebras over a field of prime characteristic, combining Schur's Lemma with a generalized version of Nakayama's Lemma and the Hilbert Nullstellensatz.   Is there a simpler version?  (And other natural examples besides enveloping algebras where the same hypotheses are satisfied?)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't recall a reference where the above statement
is proved. Other examples besides enveloping algebras (in char. p)
include symplectic reflection algebras (of Etingof-Ginzburg) in
positive characteristic, and symplectic reflection algebras with
parameter t=0 in any characteristic.
 

Comment: Let me add more details to the proof. Let V be a simple A-module. Without loss of generality we may assume that the annihilator of V is 0. Let Z denote the center of A. It follows that V is f.g. Z-module and any nonzero element of Z acts invertibly on V (Schur's lemma).
If Z is not a field, then there is a non-invertible element b in Z.
We have that bV=V, Nakayama's lemma gives that some element of 1+bZ  annihilates V, a contradiction. So Z is a field, but by the assumption Z is a finitely generated algebra over an algebraically closed field k. Therefore Z=k and V is f.g. over k. 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doc, this is a stinker. Your condition (2) forces your algebra to be finitely generated PI, and every little hare knows that simple modules over such algebras are finite-dimensional. See 13.4.9 and 13.10.3 of McConnell-Robson...